# Reset plot settings in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Im having some problem just plotting standard ggplots, probably because of some settings have changed that I'm not aware of. For example:

```
a0 <- 10; b0 <- 3
ph <- function(phi){return(1/2*dbeta((phi + 1)/2,a0,b0))}
phi_plot <- ggplot(data = data.frame(phi = c(0.5,1)),aes(phi)) + 
stat_function(fun = ph,n = 500) + xlim(c(0.3,1)) + 
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Prior distribution ", phi))) + 
  xlab(expression(phi)) + 
  ylab("Prior")  + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
phi_plot
```

produces this plot: 
[image]

I don´t know why the background is white and the axis disappears. Does anybody know how to reset the settings to default?

Comment: Maybe you changed the default theme using `theme_set`? If so, quickest fix is probably to just restart your R session.

Comment: `theme_set(theme_grey())` should restore the default.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'd tried to restart the R session several times without success and ran `dev.off()`. But when I did it now it fixed it! I don't know why. I feel kind of stupid now, but I have no idea why it didn't work earlier. Anyway, thank you very much!